# Polymer ignores paper-card margin

Tags: html, css, polymer

I want to modify the margin of paper-card elements, so I simply created a style html file. here's the relevant code:

```
paper-card {
    max-width: 400px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 10px;
    --paper-card-header-color: var(--paper-pink-a200);
}
```

Both header color and vertical-align are being applied properly, but margin and max-width are being ignored (Chrome dev console says that these values have been overriden for some reason).
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `--paper-card` mixin to apply the style like below

```
.with-margin {
  --paper-card:{
    margin: 10px;
  }
}

<paper-card class="with-margin"></paper-card>
```

Working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/xoxewe/edit?html,output

Comment: Doesn't work as well, margin is still 40px even though I've defined it to be 10px

Comment: @CaptainKopp You have check if you are over writing this style somewhere else. Or, you might not have included the style. If you post your complete code, someone might be able to help you.

Comment: And I just found my actual problem: I've overriden these properties at the end of my stylesheet. Wow. I'm genius.